# Redis - Connection refused

Tags: php, redis

I am currently testing reading on Redis with a script PHP (with the driver predis).

I have a client in which I make run the script with php-cli and a server where there is the database Redis.

My problem :

When I run the script, I have the message "connection refused" when excuting :

```
if ($redis->exists($key)) {
    //processing...
}
```

Any ideas ?  thanks.

Comment: test from the shell.. can you do a `telnet host_of_redis 6379` ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure that you test the statements you use to access the database, prior to your script running them, that way you know they work.  "Connection Refused" sounds like its not the line that you referenced in your post, but instead the connection string that is before it.

Comment: With Predis, make sure you wrap the connection in a trycatch statement. Predis throws exceptions

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Now it works I don't exactly know what I corrected...Surely a problem to reach the Redis server.

Answer (score -1):

You Need to start REDIS server. because of sometime it is confused in port number and local host. so if you got error "connection refused" then fire command  like this :

```
nohup redis-server &
```